# How to use If else in SQL Select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below select statement.

```
WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT MAX(logDate) AS Daily
   FROM PhysicalDriveSize
   GROUP BY DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, logDate), 0)
)
SELECT CAST(MIN(t.logDate) AS DATE) AS [Date], Drive, MIN(t.Free) AS [PercentagFree]
FROM PhysicalDriveSize AS t
JOIN cte AS m
ON t.logDate = m.Daily
WHERE t.Free <= 10 AND t.Free >= 0 
GROUP BY Drive, logDate
```

I want to do some actions based on the results for ex.

```
WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT MAX(logDate) AS Daily
   FROM PhysicalDriveSize
   GROUP BY DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, logDate), 0)
)
SELECT MIN(t.Free) AS [PercentagFree]
FROM PhysicalDriveSize AS t
JOIN cte AS m
ON t.logDate = m.Daily
WHERE t.Free <= 10 AND t.Free >= 0 
GROUP BY Drive, logDate
IF t.Free <= 10 AND t.Free >= 5
PRINT 'Warning'
Else
PRINT 'Critical'
```

I get the below error if I perform if statement:

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 13 The multi-part identifier "t.Free" could not be bound. Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 13 The multi-part identifier "t.Free" could not be bound
```

how can I engage if statement without errors??

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
The multi-part identifier "t.Free" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
The multi-part identifier "t.Free" could not be bound.

Comment: you should be using a case statmement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `case when then` like this:

```
WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT MAX(logDate) AS Daily
   FROM PhysicalDriveSize
   GROUP BY DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, logDate), 0)
)
SELECT MIN(t.Free) AS [PercentagFree],
case when t.Free <= 10 AND t.Free >= 5 then 'Warning'
     else 'Critical' end
FROM PhysicalDriveSize AS t
JOIN cte AS m
ON t.logDate = m.Daily
WHERE t.Free <= 10 AND t.Free >= 0 
GROUP BY Drive, logDate
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to send the message you can try to create a temp variable like

```
DECLARE @x int;
WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT MAX(logDate) AS Daily
   FROM PhysicalDriveSize
   GROUP BY DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, logDate), 0)
)
SELECT @x = MIN(t.Free) AS [PercentagFree]
FROM PhysicalDriveSize AS t
JOIN cte AS m
ON t.logDate = m.Daily
WHERE t.Free <= 10 AND t.Free >= 0 
GROUP BY Drive, logDate
if(@x is not null)
   PRINT 'Warning'
Else
   PRINT 'Critical'
```

Comment: I got the below error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'case'."

Comment: @user1071629:- Comma was misisng. Update that. try now!

Comment: The code is working, but the purpose is to send alert mail after then instead of warning and critical.

Comment: @user1071629:- Not sure if I understand it correctly. I have updated my code. Were you looking for this?

Comment: @user1071629:- Also I have removed the condition `t.Free <= 10 AND t.Free >= 0` from `if` since you are already checking that in your `where` clause

Comment: Thanx Rahul its working with temp variable, appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

you can use like this :

```
IF(t.Free <= 10 AND t.Free >= 0, 'Warning', 'Critical') as free
```

Comment: What about the `t.Free >= 0` condition?